# В чём разница между днём и сутками?

Tags: терминология

Простите за очень глупый вопрос, но в чём разница между днём и сутками (любые 24 часа)? И что в быту имеется в виду? Сутки?

Comment: Попробуйте сформулировать поточнее. "Имеется в виду" - когда, кем? Примеры бы помогли.

Comment: Просто в быту. Например: ребенок начал,Что-то делать 1-ого числа и закончила 3-его . Считается по суткам,т.е 2 дня? Или по дням? Значит 3 дня?

Comment: Просто замечаю,что многие считают по суткам,а кто-то по дням . И в чем разница?Или сутки это любые 24 часа,а дни это все дни подряд (считается начало и конец процесса)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут интересно то, что слово «день» имеет два значения: 1 Период от рассвета до заката и 2 Календарный день или сутки.
При расчетах официальных, скорее всего, берется второе значение, равное суткам. Но в быту, где царит разговорный язык, это зависит от личного восприятия каждого.

Comment: Т.е сутки это любые 24 часа , а день ~12 часов? Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Сутки — 24 часа, а день может быть разный.

Answer (score 0):

В аспекте формального отсчёта времени сутками измеряют **непрерывную** длительность временных интервалов (единица измерения равна 24 часам), а днями - **дискретную**, в форме целочисленного интервала между **датами**, напр. числами месяца (единица измерения - день). Примеры: работать (дежурить) *сутки* через трое, ответ на обращение - через 10 (рабочих, банковских и т. п.) *дней*.