# Через день и через два дня

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно понимать?
"Через день" — например, сегодня что-то делаешь, завтра отдых, а послезавтра опять? А "через два дня" — сегодня, завтра, а послезавтра должно быть выполнено? Или это послепослезавтра?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Через неделю — это когда?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443951/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

Первая мысль правильная:

- на следующий день — завтра;
- через день — послезавтра;
- через два дня — послепослезавтра.

А с секундой, минутой, неделей, месяцем, годом и веком иначе: отсчитывается этот промежуток от текущего момента. Точно или примерно.

Вот что ещё интересно — об уже упомянутых вами *сутках.* В определённом смысле день — это сутки, но *"через день"* значит ***послезавтра***, пока неизвестно, в какое время, а *"через сутки" — **завтра**, примерно или точно в это же время.*

Comment: Об уже упомянутых вами сутках? Когда? Где?

Comment: Вот: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458737/В-чём-разница-между-днём-и-сутками.

Comment: Значит,чтобы рассчитать дату, надо от даты считать (т.е не с текущим днём). Так?Спасибо!

Comment: Да, с пропуском одного дня после текущего. Или большего количества дней.